# Finding geographic coordinates of shapefile using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcmap, geojson, coordinates

I want my Python script to check if the first coordinate in a GeoJSON polygon is within a polygon in ArcMap, and if so draw the polygon to a featureclass. My issue is that the GeoJSON file is using GCS while the coordinates I get from my shapefile are in PCS.

```py
desc = arcpy.Describe(boundary)
xmin = desc.extent.XMin
ymin = desc.extent.YMin  

if xmin < Geopoint and ymin < Geopoint:
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(feature_class, ['SHAPE@']) as cursor:
        cursor.insertRow([lst])
else:
    pass
```

How can I get the x and y min or max of my boundary shape in PCS so that I can compare it to my GeoJSON point which is in GCS?

I feel like there must be a ArcPy function but I cannot seem to find it.

I am also aware that there may be simple ways to do this in ArcGIS Pro, however my organization does not use ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `arcpy.Project_management()` to convert from one coordinate system to another (including to/from a projected from/to a geographic CRS).

See the documentation at:  [Project](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm)

You could convert either your shapefile, or your GeoJSON to an `in_memory` feature class with the same CRS as the other, and then work with that in_memory feature class instead of the original.

Answer (score 2):

The `arcpy.Geometry` type supports a `projectAs(spatial_reference, {transformation_name})` request, so it should be simple to project a singleton point (`PointGeometry`) from GeoJSON to the spatial reference of your target layer.

Of course, projecting the point is only the first step in your process, since selection and rendering is done at a layer level, not simple geometry.